# Exposed views filter block refuses to show up on a page

Tags: drupal, view

I'm trying to make a facebook app version of an existing page and am having a major issue: my exposed filter block isn't showing up.

I'm using themekey to switch to a facebook version of my theme for the url the facebook version of the page is on. When my page is displayed in my normal theme it works fine, the filter is there, all is good. In my special theme there is nothing. Thing is...the special theme is a straight copy of the normal theme (with the .info modified and all the template functions removed). The block is in the preface middle region, and

```
<?php
print $preface_middle; 
?>
```

is still in the page template for that page.
On my dev site I tried to simplify matters by making the facebook theme the site wide theme (thinking that themekey was throwing things off somehow) and I had the same issue. Eventually I fixed it (somehow) on my dev site, but when I tried to use those same fixes on the live site they didn't work.

What can prevent a block with exposed filters from displaying when it should be? Like I said, when I turn off themekey the filters are there, Drupal clearly knows that the filters should be displayed at that url. I'm going nuts...what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you go to blocks section of your site: you need to add the block to the preface_middle section in the theme you want.

so:

1. Make sure the "facebook" theme is active
2. Go to blocks section and click on the "fascebook theme"
3. Move the block to the section you want for this theme.

Comment: I forgot to update this post, but this turned out to be the problem. But figuring this out led to more questions, like, why didn't this come up previously? I had already created multiple apps using the same method without this issue ever arising. Frustrating, but it all works now so at least I don't have to worry about it.